# How to get Max average value and its Id grouped by month

Tags: mysql, sql

I want the max Average value and its id grouped by month,

```
Select FK_Transporter,Month, MAX(avg_rate) as BTPercent
FROM (
    SELECT kpi.FK_Transporter ,kpi.`Month`, AVG(kpi.OnTimeDelivery) as avg_rate
    FROM primarykpi as kpi,transporter as t
        WHERE kpi.FK_Transporter=t.Id and YEAR(kpi.`Month`)=2016
    GROUP BY FK_Transporter, MONTH(kpi.Month)) tp
GROUP BY tp.`Month`
```

This query gave me right average but id is incorrect. Couldn't able to find the mistake .Here is output of this query

```
FK_Transporter       Month             MaxAvg
1                    2016-01-01        2.270109534263611
1                    2016-02-01        0.8539329767227173
1                    2016-03-01        0.6764709949493408
```

FK_transporter is 1 in all records whch is wrong . How can i fix this. Thanks.

Here is a fiddle link
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02d7c/1/0

Comment: You should learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you only group by per month in the outer query, so mysql pretty much picks the 1st fk_transporter value it encounters while scanning the results of the inner subquery. In the outer query you need to get the max averages per month and join this back on the inner subselect to get the results:

```
SELECT t2.fk_transporter, t.month, t.btpercent
FROM
(Select `Month`, MAX(avg_rate) as BTPercent
FROM (
    SELECT kpi.FK_Transporter ,kpi.`Month`, AVG(kpi.OnTimeDelivery) as avg_rate
    FROM primarykpi as kpi,transporter as t
        WHERE kpi.FK_Transporter=t.Id and YEAR(kpi.`Month`)=2016
    GROUP BY FK_Transporter, MONTH(kpi.Month)) tp
GROUP BY tp.`Month`) t
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT kpi.FK_Transporter ,kpi.`Month`, AVG(kpi.OnTimeDelivery) as avg_rate
    FROM primarykpi as kpi,transporter as t
        WHERE kpi.FK_Transporter=t.Id and YEAR(kpi.`Month`)=2016
    GROUP BY FK_Transporter, MONTH(kpi.Month)) t2
ON t2.Month=t.month and t2.avg_rate=t.btpercent
```

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02d7c/3)

Answer (score -1):

Any non-calculated columns in select should be included in your Group By

As a result you need a new wrapper of sub-query:

Step 1 - your original SQL (correct):

```
SELECT kpi.FK_Transporter, kpi.Month, AVG(kpi.OnTimeDelivery) avg_rate
FROM primarykpi kpi, transporter t
WHERE kpi.FK_Transporter=t.Id and YEAR(kpi.Month)=2016
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Step 2 - Find month with max AVG

```
SELECT tp.Month, max(tp.avg_rate) max_avg_rate
FROM (
    SELECT kpi.FK_Transporter, kpi.Month, AVG(kpi.OnTimeDelivery) avg_rate
    FROM primarykpi kpi, transporter t
    WHERE kpi.FK_Transporter=t.Id and YEAR(kpi.Month)=2016
    GROUP BY 1,2
) as tp
GROUP BY 1
```

Step 3 - Join with step 1 to find the final result:

```
SELECT tp.*
FROM (
    SELECT tp.Month, max(tp.avg_rate) max_avg_rate
    FROM (
        SELECT kpi.FK_Transporter, kpi.Month, AVG(kpi.OnTimeDelivery) avg_rate
        FROM primarykpi kpi, transporter t
        WHERE kpi.FK_Transporter=t.Id and YEAR(kpi.Month)=2016
        GROUP BY 1,2
    ) as tp
    GROUP BY 1
) as t2, (
        SELECT kpi.FK_Transporter, kpi.Month, AVG(kpi.OnTimeDelivery) avg_rate
        FROM primarykpi kpi, transporter t
        WHERE kpi.FK_Transporter=t.Id and YEAR(kpi.Month)=2016
        GROUP BY 1,2
) as tp
WHERE t2.Month=tp.Month and t2.max_avg_rate=tp.avg_rate
```

Comment: This is a feature of mysql and configurable at that. There is no attempt to brainwash anyone. Btw, mysql is not the only rdbms that allows such fields in the select list which are neither in the group by clause or is subject to a group by function. Not just simply a calculated field.